# How to Include/Use Composer Bootstrap in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I want to include/use bootstrap in all my controllers/views without having to load each css/js in each view file, so I have done this:

Installed Composer Bootstrap

`composer require twbs/bootstrap`

My Index Controller:

```
public function index() {
    // Composer Autoloader
    require VENDORPATH.'autoload.php';
    require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

    echo '<div class="section jumbotron text-center">Yu in index son.</div>';
}
```

`VENDORPATH = myhomefolder../vendor/`

vendor/autoload.php

```
// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit9d54f40b1177ed0ebd8d1d378ec06d06::getLoader();
```

/composer.json

```
{
  "require": {
    "twbs/bootstrap": "^3.3"
  }
}
```

I don't know what to do now, I have searched all the web but it only says things about other packages or something not related and Im stuck in this right now, if someone in advance can help, I would appreciate, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**

create header and footer which consists of bootstrap css and js
and put them into a templates folder in your views folder

**In controller** use them like this to every method:

```
public function index() {

  $data['title'] = 'home';
  $this->load->view('templates/bootstrap_header',$data);
  $this->load->view('index',$data);
  $this->load->view('templates/bootstrap_footer');
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to get all CSS/JS within the autoload, like pre-loaded css/js in every controller Instead of loading view with header/footer?

Comment: no you can not autoload css and js library,helper databases can be autoload

Comment: this is the simplest method as far as know.Use base_url or site_url include the css and js

Comment: Alright, thank you for you help, I will mark you answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

What I do, is that I use a "main" template, which includes the css, js, head, body, etc... Then, inside my body tag, I do the $this->load->view('folder/function', $data); which processes the internal view... Do I make sense ???

Main View:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <?php $this->load->view('html/head', $view_data); ?>
        </head>
        <body lang="es">

            <div class="container">

                <?php $this->load->view('html/header')?> 
        
                <div class="contenido">

                    <?php if (isset($which_view))  $this->load->view($which_view, $view_data)?>

                </div>
                <?php $this->load->view('html/footer');?>
            </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

And finally, I create a small "inner-view" in a folder named after my controller, named after my function , so everything stays in sync...

```html
<div class="formatoLogin modulo">
 
 <?php echo form_open('login/doLogin', array('id'=>'formLogin', 'class'=>'form-signin'))?>

  <?php $this->load->view('mod/notificacion')?>   
  <h1>Acceso Restringido</h1>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="Usuario" class="control-label">Usuario:</label>
   <input type="text" name="Usuario" id="Usuario" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="Contrasenia" class="control-label">Contraseña:</label>
   <input type="password" name="Contrasenia" id="Contrasenia"  class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group text-center">
   <button class="btn btn-info">Acceder</button>
  </div>
  <?php if($this->uri->segment(3)=='redirect'){?>
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $this->uri->segment(4).'/' . $this->uri->segment(5).'/' . $this->uri->segment(6) ?>">
  <?php } ?>
 <?php echo form_close()?>
</div>
```

Do I make sense? I hope it works cause it's saved me tons of includes...